# configure IQKeyboardManager without internet or using library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iqkeyboardmanager

I want to add `IQKeyboardManager` to my iOS app, I'm using Mac in VirtualBox.
Are there any libraries or have I got to go with a Pod?
If there is a way, give...

Comment: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager here you can download the zip file locally and add IQKeyBoardMangaer class to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Just download source file for `IQKeyboardManager` from [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) and follow following steps.

**Objective-C :**
Just drag and drop `IQKeyBoardManager` directory from demo project to your project.

**Swift :**
Drag and drop `IQKeyBoardManagerSwift` directory from demo project to your project